# How to get html of ngformio include data components?

Tags: angular-forms, formio

I use ngformio to generate form for user input data. I need to send email form content with data. But when form submitted, i only receive form html without data components. So how can i get form html include data components when form submitted? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Form.io uses [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) for all of its email template. Within the Form.io email action, there are a number of Nunjucks "macros" that can be used to include Form data within your emails. These are provided here.

https://help.form.io/userguide/actions/#nunjucks-templating

This allows you to print out the entire submission in table format as follows.

`{{ submission(data, components) }}`

Orif you wish to print out a single field data you can use the following.

`{{ value('yourField') }}`

Where `yourField` would be the API key of your field within your form.